# How to display an image from database to background-image css property in laravel?

Tags: css, laravel

I want to display image from database to background-image css property inside **carousel slider**. But cannot make it work. Its blank.

**My code:**

```
<div class="ec-slide-item d-flex slide-10" style="background-image: url({{env('APP_URL')}}.'/'.{{$product->image}});">
```

The value of $product->image is 'assets/images/dgfgsgs.jpg'.
The whole url is correct. But still not working. Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try:

```
 <div class="ec-slide-item d-flex slide-10" style="background-image: url('{{ asset($product->image) }}');">
```

instead the variable $product->image should return a result like this: 'images/dgfgsgs.jpg'

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<div class="ec-slide-item d-flex slide-10" style="background-image: url({{ asset($product->image ) }})">
```